# TeX Live version under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tex-live

my server has as operation system: Ubuntu 12.04.05 LTS.

Because my goal is to generate some .tex-files on my server I installed TeX Live.
So I executed this command in the shell:

```
apt-get install texlive -full
```

It installed about 1.7 Gb.

When I now execute the following:

```
tex --version
```

It get the information:

> TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 5.0.0
>   Copyright 2009 D.E. Knuth.
>   There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
>   covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the TeX source.
>   Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.

And this is what I don't understand, why isn't there the newer version of TeX Live?

Greetings

Comment: most of the 1.7Gb are docs and language packs though - this is why I don't install the -full package any more

Comment: and why is there an TeX Live version 2009? Is this a default package of Ubuntu or I installed it with my apt-get install texlive -full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**why isn't there the newer version of TeX Live?**

Packages for example the linux kernel don't get major version updates during a ubuntu release because of stability reasons.

Maybe you can use the tex live [Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) ([https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Etexlive-backports/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) to install a newer version.

After adding the ppa to your system you can install the newer version:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install texlive-full

Comment: Ok, I also could live with the 2009 version. I didn't even know it's already installed . So was it a big mistake that I executed: apt-get install texlive -full ? Do I have do uninstall it or is everything fine?

Comment: I think you can upgrade without uninstall by adding the ppa and the 2 commands. (Only if you want a newer Version). The only negative thing with a full install is that all languages are installed, but if you can life with this, i think everything is fine. Mark the question as answered, other questions would be a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: When I use `-full`, apt-get complains that it doesn't know command line option `-l` (it kows `-f` and `-u`). Is that what you intended? Do I have a different version of `apt-get`?

Comment: the package name is "texlive-full" the space is wrong (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive-full)